# How to properly use Pattern in Java with a String of numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use `Pattern` in Java and I'm having a problem.

I want to find from a `String[]` that contains numbers (that I retrieved from a file) if they match another string of numbers (also from a file).

E.g. I have the number `1` and I want to search in a String like this: 
`5 10 1 8 6 3 -1 10 8 10 10 4 10 -1 10 10 10 10 9 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 -2`.

Obviously the `-1` and `10` are not what I'm locking for. Is there a way to solve this?

I can't use use `Pattern.compile()` with an integer.

Comment: Please edit your question to show with what `String` you start, and what `String` you are trying to find.

Comment: So what do you actually have a String or an *array* of strings?

Comment: Whatever you do, split the input by space and search on it, or parse the string into an array of numbers and work on it. It's not clear why you are trying to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

### Pattern

Numbers in file are seperated by spaces,so you can write pattern like this

```
String number = "1";
String file = "5 10 1 8 6 3 -1 10 8 10 10 4 10 -1 10 10 10 10 9 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10 10 -1 -2";
file = " " + file + " "; // this is a hack to make the pattern to be right
boolean matches = Pattern.matches(".*\\s+" + number + "\\s+.*", file);
System.out.println(matches); // => true
```

If your remove '1' from the file, the match will be false.Because of the spaces, it will not match '-1' and '10' int the file.

ps: because of the pattern only matches the number surrounded by spaces, if the number is in the begining of the file, and there is no space in front of the number, it will not match. So I do the hack.

### split the file to array

You can split the file(also with seprator space) into array, then iterate and compare.